# Vector of class not returning length

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of classes: `vector<qANDa> spanish;` and I want it to return the length, and I'm using the code: `int a = spanish.length();`, but it says, `No member named 'length' in 'std::__1::vector<qANDa, std::__1::allocator<qANDa> >'`. So I basically want to know why on earth this is.

Comment: A [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would have told you how to fix this straight away.

Comment: you'd get the answer is about 5 seconds if you googled it

Comment: You don't even need a reference, the compiler told you what the problem is!

Comment: My favorite reference is: [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: I use C++ reference, but again, I was looking over my code and say `length()`, and I didn't look close enough to see it was for a string, not a vector. As you can tell, I'm terrible at C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

```
int a = spanish.size();
```

`std::vector<T>` has no member named `length()`

Comment: Okay, I was looking at getting the length of strings earlier, which use `length()`. Thank you.

Comment: @newbie, Note `size()` is also in `string`